# How do i access android 'hint' style from my custom component?

Tags: android

I have created my own custom component and would like to use android 'hint' style like this:

```
   <com.sheep.EmailListContainer
        android:id="@+id/my_component"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Hint To Use"/>
```

So my question is, how do i get the 'hint' style from attribute set in the constructor of my component (to use it for my component)?

- i have looked how it's down in TextView for example, and i see that it's trying to access android.internal.R.styleable which i do not have access to

Thanks in advance
Lior

Comment: Can you post the relevant code of EmailListContainer? What is his superclass?

Comment: It's super class is just a LinearLayout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this method:

```
public static final String DEFAULT_NAMESPACE = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android";

private String getDefaultNamespaceAttributeValue(AttributeSet attrs, String attribute) {
    String value = null;

    int resId = attrs.getAttributeResourceValue(DEFAULT_NAMESPACE, attribute, 0);
    if (resId != 0) {
        value = getContext().getResources().getString(resId);
    } else {
        value = attrs.getAttributeValue(DEFAULT_NAMESPACE, attribute);
    }

    return value;
}
```

Then use like this:

```
public EmailListContainer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

    String value = getDefaultNamespaceAttributeValue(attrs, "hint");
}
```